# WCF Service Datetime parse error on different clients

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I have an issue regarding consumption of a WCF service:

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "list_LogUser")]
 DTO.Responses.List_LogUser list_LogUser(DTO.Requests.Token token);
```

Request:

```
public class Token
{
    public string ApiToken { get; set; }
}
```

Response:

```
public class List_LogUsuario
{
    public List<Select.LogUser> LogUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Class:

```
public class LogUser
{
   public int IdLogUser { get; set; }
   public string User { get; set; }
   public string Action { get; set; }
   public string Class { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public DTO.Responses.List_LogUser list_LogUser(DTO.Requests.Token token)
{
    try
    {
        DTO.Responses.List_LogUsuario response = new DTO.Responses.List_LogUsuario();

        if (BBSessionManager.Instance.validateAPIKEY(token.ApiToken))
        {
            response.LogUsers = new List<Select.LogUser>();
            Select.LogUser l = new Select.LogUser();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[clientConnString].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
            {
                SqlConn.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(spName, SqlConn);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sda.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                SqlConn.Close();
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
                sda.Dispose();
            }

            DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                l = Utils.logUser_parse(rows[i]);
                response.LogUsers.Add(l);
            }

            response.Response = Constants.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            response.Response = Constants.ERROR;
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

BD Parser:

```
public static Select.LogUser logUser_parse(DataRow r)
    {
        Select.LogUser l = new Select.LogUser();
        ...
        l.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(r["Date"].ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        ...

        return l;
    }
```

I have tried using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` on `DateTime.ParseExact` but still no results. What is more curious is that when I locally run it on my laptop it works but from my office PC it gives me the ERROR. I tested it from two another laptops, one with no error another with same error. I do not know if I am not using DateTime.ParseExact  correctly or if I'm missing something else.

StackTrace:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)    at
>   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider
>   provider)

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the debugger and see what the string looks like.

Comment: Are you sure `r["Date"].ToString()` always contains a valid date?

Comment: Yes, I set breakpoint on it. Even updated all rows in table with GETDATE() just for testing purposes but the error persists. As I explained from different computers I have different behaviors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet what is happening is that the computer that is giving you trouble has has a different date format - see Control Panel -> Region -> Formats

The best thing for you to do is try to TryParseExact the format of that computer.

A better option would be to do something like `date.ToString("o")` which will force the DateTime string to be in a universal format that you should have no problem parsing.

Comment: tried:

    DateTime var;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(r["Date"].ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out var);

with: r["Date"].ToString() as 23/07/2014 12:11:18 a.m. and obtained 01/01/0001 12:00:00 a.m. :(

Comment: Is r["Date"] what you are trying to parse?  If it is, is it a string?  If so, you don't need to call ToString() on it.  Second, assuming it is a string the format you need is "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

Comment: still same error, I'm getting a False return from DateTime.TryParseExact() :'(, this error is so rare been months in it still haven't find universal solution.

Comment: r["Date"] is of type Datetime, but everytime I try to assign directly I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime". So I tried to parse it. Feeling dumb right now: tried l.Date = (DateTime)r["Date"]; and worked :'(, thanks for the insight I'd never figure it out by myself.

Comment: Still can figure out why any of Datetime parsers worked before :O. Anyways thanks again.